# Definition and existence of Riemann integral in PMA Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, integration

[image]

I understand all moments bseides $(1)$ and $(2)$. Why Rudin considers $\inf U(P,f)$ and $\sup L(P,f)$. Why we can't considered $\sup U(P,f)$ and $\inf L(P,f)$?

Can anyone explain it to me please?

Comment: Think about the [picture of the upper and lower sums](https://math4allages.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/geogebra18-4.png).  Clearly you want the lowest possible value (infimum) of the set of *upper* sums and the supremum of the *lower* sums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This boils down to the fact that if $P'\supseteq P$, then $U(P',f)\le U(P,f)$.  So, the finer the partition of $[a,b]$ the smaller the value of $U(P,f)$.

The idea in Riemann integration is to approximate $\int_a^b$ by taking finer and finer partitions of $[a,b]$.  So the values $(P,f)$ approach $\int_a^b$ by getting smaller and smaller.

So,if we were to let $\overline\int=\sup$ and $\underline\int=\inf$ the integeral would have little chance of converging.

Comment: Dear Tim. I read what you wrote but I can't understand. How this answer to my question? Can you expain please?

Comment: Not sure what you're not understanding.  It might help if I knew why you think lettting $\overline\int=\sup$ is a good idea.

Comment: I can't understand what relation between my question and your answer.

Comment: I've expanded my answer a little.  Does that help?

Comment: I can't understand what problems would be if we let $\overline\int=\sup$ and $\underline\int=\inf$? You wrote that the integral would have little chance of converging. But can it be explained more strictly?

Comment: How about this:  The larger the value of $U(P,f)$ the further away it is from the actual value of $\int_a^b$.

Comment: It quite better. Thank you very much, Tim!

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: @RFZ Just for an example, consider the function $f:[0,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=0$ if $0 \leq x \leq 1$; and $f(x)=1$ if $1 <x \leq 2 $.

By **your proposed definition**, $\overline{\int}f=1$ and $\underline{\int} f=0$.